# Making events not trigger so often on a datatable with dc.js

Tags: javascript, performance, data-visualization

I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116676/3164679) to make a table with datatables.net and dc.js.  However, I detected a performance issue in this loop:

```
function RefreshTable() {
    dc.events.trigger(function () {
        datatable.api()
        .clear()
        .rows.add( YearDimension.top(Infinity) )
        .draw() ;
    });
}

count = dc.chartRegistry.list().length
for (var i=count; i--;) {
    dc.chartRegistry.list()[i].on("filtered", RefreshTable);
}
RefreshTable() ;
```

Because when resetting all the filters with

```
dc.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();
```

`RefreshTable()` is executed once for every `dc` chart (or dimension?). In my case it's 5 loops at ~500ms each, thus more than 2s for 4 charts and 10k records.

Has someone any idea on how to make it faster? The table should be refreshed only once.

Comment: Why is this not allowed ? >2 seconds is more a bug than a performance issue to me. And this could be usefull to others.

Comment: I think this is a problem with the way the question was phrased. It turns out to be a question about the API but indeed the title makes it look like a code review question.

Comment: Okay I read this wrong. Indeed it is a code review question.

Answer (score 1):

What is ineficient here is always running RefreshTable 5 times. Even if no filters where applied to any charts.

Make a new function that only resets filters from charts that have a filter.

```
function filterAll_performance(){
    var chartlist=[chart_year, chart_genre, chart_runtime, chart_globalscore]
    count=chartlist.length;
    for (var i=count; i--;) {
        if(chartlist[i].filters()!=0) {
            chartlist[i].filterAll();
        }
    }
}
```

and replace

```
dc.filterAll();
```

with

```
filterAll_performance();
```

This will still refresh the datatable more than once sometimes but it's still better.

Comment: Congratulations, a very rare piece of well-written selfie answer :-)